# MySQL Dump to tar.gz from remote without shell access

Tags: linux, shell, mysql, pipe, tar

I'm trying to get a dump from MySQL to my local client. This is what I currently have:

`mysqldump -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS $db | gunzip -9 > $FILE`

What I want though is .tar.gz instead of a gunzip archive. I have shell access on local client but not on the server. So, I can't do a remote tar and copy it here. So, is there a way of piping the gzip to a tar.gz. (Currently, the .gz does not get recognized as a tar archive.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are issuing the above command in client side, your compression is done in client side. mysqldump connects the remote server and downloads the data without any compression.

```
mysqldump -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS $db > filename
tar cfz filename.tar.gz filename
rm filename
```

Probably some unix gurus will have a one liner to do it.

Comment: mysqldump -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS $db > filename; tar cfz filename.tar.gz filename; rm filename     :D

Comment: Good answer. Should've thought of that myself but thanks. I'll still keep looking for a one-liner, as you said.

Comment: My guess is that the use of intermediate file is necessary, if you can tar stdout then the result of untar doesn't make much sense, or does it? I searched around and I couldn't find anything. Making a one liner by Separating the commands by semicoloncould be the best way

Comment: I think I get it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NylonSmile , If I want the backup to go into my /private/ folder, how would I modify this script? Also, will this script overwrite files with the same filename? And lastly, I'm on a shared hosting, can only connect via localhost. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No. The files (yes, plural, since tar is usually used for more than one file) are first placed in a tar archive, and *then* that is compressed. If you are trying to use the `tar` command line tool then you will need to save the result in a temporary file and then tar that.

Personally though, I'd rather hit the other side with a cluebat.

Comment: Agree with the intermediate file. I don't really understand that last comment though.

Comment: It's quite simple. There is **no** justification for putting it in a tar archive since it's a single file.

Answer (score 2):

`mysqldump -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS $db | tar -zcvf $FILE -`

Where $FILE is your filename.tar.gz

Comment: Doesn't work. Errors like: 
tar: -- MySQL dump 10.11: Cannot stat: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

Archived backup and renamed by time and date:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS $db | gzip -c > /home/backup_`/bin/date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M"`.gz
```